# What is the source of the Panchakanya sloka?

Tags: women, shloka, identification-request

Does anyone know from which scripture this sloka is cited? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchakanya) doesn't help much. I've heard this sloka almost everywhere so I'm curious and want to find out it's source.

> अहल्या द्रौपदी कुन्ती तारा मन्दोदरी तथा ।
>   पञ्चकन्याः स्मरेन्नित्यं महापातकनाशिनीः ॥
>
> ahalyā draupadī kuntī tārā mandodarī tathā ।
>   pañcakanyāḥ smarennityaṃ mahāpātakanāśinīḥ ॥
>
> Ahalya, Draupadi, Kunti, Tara and Mandodari. One should forever remember the panchakanya who are the destroyers of great sins.

Also why are the names of Ahalya,Draupadi, Kunti, Tara and Mandodari 'sin-destroying'?

Comment: Related: [Why Ahalya,Tara,Mandodari,Kunti and Draupadi are called panchakanyas.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9632/277)

Comment: Read Endnote-1 at http://www.manushi-india.org/pdfs_issues/PDF%20141/03%20panchakanya%204-12.pdf

Answer (score 2):

A lot of online pages cite Brahmanda Purana 3.7.219 but it may not be the caxe.

“Ahinik Sutravali”, cf. Bharatiya Sanskriti Kosh by Liladhar Sharma ‘Parvatiya’, (Delhi: Rajpal & Sons, 2nd edition, 1996) p. 502 also cites the Brahmanda Purana, 3.7.219. The verse was not found in the editions of this Purana available in Calcutta. Sudhirchandra Sarkar’s Pauranik Abhidhan (Calcutta: M.C. Sarkar & Sons, 1963) has an entry on “Panchakanya” (p.287) giving these five names.

This shloka forms part of Orissa’s dying Mahari dance composition, kept alive by Padma Sri Guru Pankaj Charan Das, his disciple Dr. Ratna Roy and Ritha Devi.

Answer (score 1):

This hymn was created by antyastak hrishi
He told tara (wife of vali later sugriv) about ahilya (savitri i guess) how she begged yamraja for her husband, when yamraja gave back her husbands atma antyastak hrishi was there he was 6-7 year old kid he saw that and said "pativrata stree" yamraja heard it, he didn't wanted to see anyone that he gave savitri her husband back so he became angry and said him why are you here, you shoudnt be here but now u have  seen this you got power Of recognising pativrata stree! There are 5 pativrata are goings to born on this earth , so now on you are gonna recognized them and till you didnt find or recognise them and create shloka (hymn )on them u wont get mukti (death)( i am not going to release you from manushya yoni) so he Created this hymn

You can find this in book called ravanayan "रावणायण " by indrayani savkar

Comment: Can you mention exact reference (like page number) in book?

Comment: Ahilya was wife of Gautam rishi. No? Plus she was the first woman created by Brahma. No?